# How to add data to Map copying existing values based on List of identifiers

Tags: kotlin

Sorry for the poor title but it is rather hard to describe my use case in a short sentence.

#### Context

I have the following model:

```kotlin
typealias Identifier = String

data class Data(val identifier: Identifier,
                val data1: String,
                val data2: String)
```

And I have three main data structures in my use case:

- A `Set` of `Identifier`s that exist and are valid in a given context. Example:

```kotlin
val existentIdentifiers = setOf("A-1", "A-2", "B-1", "B-2", "C-1")
```

- A `Map` that contains a `List` of `Data` objects per `Identifier`. Example:

```kotlin
val dataPerIdentifier: Map<Identifier, List<Data>> = mapOf(
    "A-1" to listOf(Data("A-1", "Data-1-A", "Data-2-A"), Data("A-1", "Data-1-A", "Data-2-A")),
    "B-1" to listOf(Data("B-1", "Data-1-B", "Data-2-B")),
    "C-1" to listOf(Data("C-1", "Data-1-C", "Data-2-C"))
)
```

- A `List` of `List`s that group together the `Identifier`s that should share the same `List<Data>` (each `List` includes always 2 `Identifier`s). Example

```kotlin
val identifiersWithSameData = listOf(listOf("A-1", "A-2"), listOf("B-1", "B-2"))
```

#### Problem / Use Case

The problem that I am trying to tackle stems from the fact that `dataPerIdentifier` might not contain all `identifiersWithSameData` given that `existentIdentifiers` contains such missing `Identifier`s. I need to add those missing `Identifier` to `dataPerIdentifier`, copying the `List<Data>` already in there.

#### Example

Given the data in the Context section:

```
A-1=[Data(identifier=A-1, data1=Data-1-A, data2=Data-2-A), 
     Data(identifier=A-1, data1=Data-1-A, data2=Data-2-A)], 
B-1=[Data(identifier=B-1, data1=Data-1-B, data2=Data-2-B)], 
C-1=[Data(identifier=C-1, data1=Data-1-C, data2=Data-2-C)]
```

The desired outcome is to update `dataPerIdentifier` so that it includes:

```
A-1=[Data(identifier=A-1, data1=Data-1-A, data2=Data-2-A), 
     Data(identifier=A-1, data1=Data-1-A, data2=Data-2-A)], 
B-1=[Data(identifier=B-1, data1=Data-1-B, data2=Data-2-B)], 
C-1=[Data(identifier=C-1, data1=Data-1-C, data2=Data-2-C)], 
A-2=[Data(identifier=A-2, data1=Data-1-A, data2=Data-2-A), 
     Data(identifier=A-2, data1=Data-1-A, data2=Data-2-A)]
```

The reason is that `existentIdentifiers` contains `A-2` that is missing in the initial `dataPerIdentifier` `Map`. `B-2` is also missing in the initial `dataPerIdentifier` `Map` but `existentIdentifiers` does not contain it, so it is ignored.

#### Possible solution

I have already a working code (`handleDataForMultipleIdentifiers()` method is the one doing the heavy lifting), but it does not feel to be the cleanest or easiest to read:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val existentIdentifiers = setOf("A-1", "A-2", "B-1", "C-1")

    val dataPerIdentifier: Map<Identifier, List<Data>> = mapOf(
        "A-1" to listOf(Data("A-1", "Data-1-A", "Data-2-A"), Data("A-1", "Data-1-A", "Data-2-A")),
        "B-1" to listOf(Data("B-1", "Data-1-B", "Data-2-B")),
        "C-1" to listOf(Data("C-1", "Data-1-C", "Data-2-C"))
    )

    val identifiersWithSameData = listOf(listOf("A-1", "A-2"), listOf("B-1", "B-2"))

    print("Original Data")
    println(dataPerIdentifier)

    print("Target Data")
    println(dataPerIdentifier.handleDataForMultipleIdentifiers(identifiersWithSameData, existentIdentifiers))
}

fun Map<Identifier, List<Data>>.handleDataForMultipleIdentifiers(identifiersWithSameData: List<List<Identifier>>, existentIdentifiers: Set<Identifier>)
        : Map<Identifier, List<Data>> {
    val additionalDataPerIdentifier = identifiersWithSameData
        .mapNotNull { identifiersList ->
            val identifiersWithData = identifiersList.find { it in this.keys }
            identifiersWithData?.let { it to identifiersList.minus(it).filter { it in existentIdentifiers } }
        }.flatMap { (existentIdentifier, additionalIdentifiers) ->
            val existentIdentifierData = this[existentIdentifier].orEmpty()
            additionalIdentifiers.associateWith { identifier -> existentIdentifierData.map { it.copy(identifier = identifier) } }.entries
        }.associate { it.key to it.value }

    return this + additionalDataPerIdentifier
}

typealias Identifier = String

data class Data(val identifier: Identifier,
                val data1: String,
                val data2: String)
```

So my question is: how can I do this in a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `identifiersWithSameData` always contains 2 identifiers per item then it should not really be a list of lists, but rather a list of pairs or dedicated data classes. And if you convert this data structure into a map like this:

```kotlin
val identifiersWithSameData = mapOf("A-1" to "A-2", "A-2" to "A-1", "B-1" to "B-2", "B-2" to "B-1")
```

The the whole solution is pretty simple:

```kotlin
existentIdentifiers.associateWith {
    dataPerIdentifier[it] ?: dataPerIdentifier[identifiersWithSameData[it]!!]!!
}
```

I'm not sure about both `!!`, for example I don't know if it is guaranteed that identifier existing in `existentIdentifiers` exists in `identifiersWithSameData` as well. You may need to tune this solution a little.